# keeping track of an image javascript

Tags: javascript

So im creating my own slider using javascript. I have 12 images total. 6 50x50, and 6 200x200.  The smaller images switch from 1,2,3,4,5,6 and back to 1. When ever the image is clicked on a larger image is suppose to open in a new window.  The problem is when i click on the 6th smaller image and the pop up window is opened the image is broken.  I have debugged it and see the problem is that when I open up the image i am alerted that the pop is opening up 0.

Any help would be appreciated.  It is most likely something simple that I am not seeing.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
<script>

number=1
function move(){
brillo.src="images/tudelude_0"+number+".jpg"
number++

 if (number>6) number=1
 setTimeout("move()",1000)

 }


function Open(){
t=number-1

var newWindow = window.open("", "pictureViewer", "fullscreen=no");
newWindow.document.writeln("<img src='images/tude_0"+t+".jpg'/>");
alert(t)
newWindow.document.close(); 
}

</script>
</head>

<body onload="move()">

<div class="box">
 <img src="images/tudelude_01.jpg" name="brillo" 
 onclick="Open(); return true;">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Avoid implicit semicolons; always put semicolons at the end of your statements. This avoids certain subtle bugs.

Comment: Also, are your images numbered 0-5, or 1-6?

Comment: So, why do you subtract one from the `number` then?

Comment: because if i just user number and dont subtract 1 from it when i click on the image it displays the next image in the pop up window

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `number` doesn't accurately reflect what image is actually being shown.

You should do this instead:

```
number = 1;
function move() {
    number++;
    if(number > 6)
        number = 1;
    brillo.src="images/tudelude_0"+number+".jpg";
}

function Open(){
    var newWindow = window.open("", "pictureViewer", "fullscreen=no");
    newWindow.document.writeln("<img src='images/tude_0"+number+".jpg'/>");
    newWindow.document.close(); 
}
```

and in your `onload`, use `setInterval(move, 1000)`.

Comment: Oops, alway something stupid that im doing wrong. Thanks for the help.  Much appreciated.